# Discord.js bot won't ping members with a role when role is tagged

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I want to send a message to a channel and tag a role by the role's ID, all of this is okay and it doesn't throw any errors. The message mentions the role but it doesn't get the yellow background like when you've been mentioned or the red (1) next to the channel like you've been mentioned. It's able to ping individual users just fine, just pinging roles it's unable to do. Does anyone have any ideas?

My client initialization has the `allowedMentions`:

```
const client = new Client({
    allowedMentions: { parse: ['users', 'roles'], repliedUser: true },
    intents: [...]
});
```

The way I'm trying to tag the role just to make sure it works is:

1. Slash command `/test`

```
case 'test': {
    await interaction.reply(`<@&1013966888419741778>`);
} break;
```

The message that gets sent from that command looks like this:
[image]

But when I try and tag a user ( `await interaction.reply('<@479069058864775180>');` ) it works just fine: [image]

Comment: Do you have the role lol

Comment: @caTS yes i do...

Comment: Hm, well I admit it's quite odd for *you* to have a role named `Ticket Discord Bot`, but anyways, you probably have to add `allowedMentions` as seen [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#allowed-mentions).

Comment: @caTS in my original post I showed that I've already added that.

Comment: My bad, must've missed it somehow. You might want to try asking in the discord.js discord server instead.

Comment: I didn't know they had that! Do you have a link to where I can find an invite link? Thanks

Comment: You can find it just by searching `discord.js server`, but here you go: https://discord.gg/djs

Comment: Did you manage to get this fixed? Would be nice to leave the answer if you have one! :D